# AT TIME ZONE, handling multiple timezones

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I'm creating an application that needs to have the ability to handle users from multiple time-zones and display dates properly for their particular time-zone.

I've created the below code as an example of what I get, but I'm a bit confused as to what the correct method is to handle the timezone issue.

Is it best to do this through storing all dates in the database as UTC and using AT TIME ZONE accordingly, or should I be thinking another way?

```
Create Table #Test
(
    SampleDate datetimeoffset(7) 
)

Create Table #Test2
(
    SampleDate datetimeoffset(7) 
)

Create Table #Test3
(
    SampleDate datetime
)

insert into #Test select getdate()
insert into #Test2 select getdate() AT TIME ZONE 'AUS Eastern Standard Time' 
insert into #Test3 select getdate()


select 
    SampleDate, 
    SampleDate AT TIME ZONE 'AUS Eastern Standard Time',
    SampleDate AT TIME ZONE 'AUS Central Standard Time',
    SampleDate AT TIME ZONE 'Aus Central W. Standard Time'
from #Test

select 
    SampleDate, 
    SampleDate AT TIME ZONE 'AUS Eastern Standard Time',
    SampleDate AT TIME ZONE 'AUS Central Standard Time',
    SampleDate AT TIME ZONE 'Aus Central W. Standard Time'
from #Test2

select 
    SampleDate, 
    SampleDate AT TIME ZONE 'AUS Eastern Standard Time',
    SampleDate AT TIME ZONE 'AUS Central Standard Time',
    SampleDate AT TIME ZONE 'Aus Central W. Standard Time'
from #Test3

drop table #Test
drop table #Test2
drop table #Test3
```

## Test Results

```
2017-09-24 10:59:47.4233333 +00:00  
2017-09-24 20:59:47.4233333 +10:00  
2017-09-24 20:29:47.4233333 +09:30  
2017-09-24 19:44:47.4233333 +08:45
```

## Test2 Results

```
2017-09-24 10:59:47.4230000 +10:00  
2017-09-24 10:59:47.4230000 +10:00  
2017-09-24 10:29:47.4230000 +09:30  
2017-09-24 09:44:47.4230000 +08:45
```

## Test3 Results

```
2017-09-24 10:59:47.423 
2017-09-24 10:59:47.423 +10:00  
2017-09-24 10:59:47.423 +09:30  
2017-09-24 10:59:47.423 +08:45
```

Comment: If you need different timezones, use `datetimeoffset`.  That is what it is there for.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff , but what should you store in the table? Do you always store UTC or do you store the particular users date/time and offset?

Comment: . . Oh, that depends on how they are being used.  I think I tend to store them in the same timezone, but there are valid reasons for storing them in multiple local times.

Comment: Cheers, it's an interesting concept to get your head around to ensure you don't run into problems down the track with the method you've chosen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Azure database always use UTC time. For that reason you should use datetimeoffset.

You should also capture the system date using sysdatetimeoffset() instead of using getdate().

When you retrieve dates from the database tables you should then use “AT TIME ZONE”.

Hope this helps.